# xhost doesn't work for Oracle Installation

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu

In /.profile I wrote:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0;
export DISPLAY
```

and from another tty I run xhost(or Oracle DB installer), he write:

> xhost: unable to open display ":127.0.0.1"

What's wrong?

Comment: Why are setting `DISPLAY` in a *different* terminal? What happens if you set it in the *same* terminal, as `oracle`, immediately before starting the installer?

Comment: @AlexPoole no reason, but both TTY in graphic mode, so I do not think problem is here.

Comment: I disagree, they are separate shells with their own environments. The `oracle` shell clearly doesn't have the same display value - you can see that in the error you get. Did you try setting it immediately before starting the installer...?

Comment: What do you get if you run `echo $DISPLAY` on the terminal with error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try connect to the server with oracle user directly. Do not change to oracle from another user.